# Xamarin Forms: How to set title for tabbedpage?

Tags: xamarin.forms, tabs

I implement TabbedPage with 3 tabs like the following picture.

[image]

On top of these 3 tabs, I am trying to set a title, which will be common for all the 3 tabs. Tried title property of tabbedpage, but not worked.

MyTabbedpage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Myapp;assembly=Myapp"
            BarBackgroundColor="#1C7DB4"
            BarTextColor="White"
            x:Class="Myapp.MyTabbedPage">
</TabbedPage>
```

MyTabbedpage.xaml.cs

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace Myapp
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class MyTabbedPage : TabbedPage
    {
        public MyTabbedPage(bool value)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Children.Add(new Topics());
            Children.Add(new Group());
            Children.Add(new Menu());
        }

        protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/tabbed-page

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it without a custom renderer.

You may try this prebuilt form control - TabView - found at: 
https://github.com/gruan01/XFControls

You can find it also on NuGet.
You can set image onto the tabs and other enhancements.

But I strongly recommend a custom renderer as a final solution.

Comment: Can you give a sample custom renderer code for this? I am not worked on custom renders.

Comment: You'll find some custom renderers samples here and you can build your own code adapting them: start with Content page...is similar with what you want: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/CustomRenderers

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainPageCS : TabbedPage
{
  public MainPageCS ()
  {
    var navigationPage = new NavigationPage (new SchedulePageCS ());
    navigationPage.Icon = "schedule.png";
    navigationPage.Title = "Schedule";

    Children.Add (new TodayPageCS ());
    Children.Add (navigationPage);
  }
}
```

This is the code snippet from the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/tabbed-page). On line number 7 you can see how the title is set.

After you edited your question, it seems that you want to wrap your `TabbedPage` by a `NavigationPage` and set a `Title` for the `NavigationPage`. Example:

```
new NavigationPage(new MyTabbedPage()) { Title = "Common Title" };
```

Alternatively, one of your `TabbedPage` children can be a `NavigationPage` as well, depends on your needs.

Comment: This code only creates a title like topics or group in my question picture. I am trying to set a common title for all the 3 tabs.

Comment: What is a 'common title'?

Comment: "After you edited your question, it seems that you want to wrap your TabbedPage by a NavigationPage and set a Title for the NavigationPage"--- Sorry I didn't get this point.

Comment: Can you please provide the sample?